# create macro variables in python data frame

Tags: python, macros

I'm trying to automate a code as it's causing a repetitive work becasue of manually changing the column names in the code all the time. I am trying to understand how to create a macro variable in python like in SAS. Any helps is much appreciated!

```
##I'm creating my cutoff points first

#### I need to assign a value to col1 in a macro in order not to hardcode it all the time!

    cutoff1 = my_data['col1'].describe([.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7, .8, 0.9])['10%'].astype('float64')
    cutoff2 = my_data['col1'].describe([.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7, .8, 0.9])['20%'].astype('float64')
    cutoff3 = my_data['col1'].describe([.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7, .8, 0.9])['30%'].astype('float64')

    ##Then I'm assigning the new values to my continuous variables by using the thresholds I've determined above

    #### I also need to assign a value to COL1_RANK such as %s='COL1' i.e.  %s&'_RANK'

    def f(row): 

                if row['col1'] <=cutoff1 : 
                        COL1_RANK = 1 

                elif row['col1']<=cutoff2: 
                        COL1_RANK = 2 

                elif row['col1']<=cutoff3: 
                        COL1_RANK = 3 

                 else : 
                        COL1_RANK = 4
                return COL1_RANK


    my_data['COL1_RANK'] = my_data.apply(f, axis=1) 

    my_data.head(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need create custom function with [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html) and [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
def func(df, input_col, output_col):
    cutoffs = df[input_col].quantile([.1,.2,.3]).astype('float64')
    bins = [-np.inf, cutoffs[.1], cutoffs[.2], cutoffs[.3], np.inf]
    labels=[1,2,3,4]

    df[output_col] = pd.cut(df[input_col], bins=bins, labels=labels)
    return df

my_data = func(my_data, 'col1', 'COL1_RANK')
```

Comment: one quick question, if I wanted to give some manual cut-off points rather than quantiles, how could I do that? For example, instead quantile([.1,.2,.3]) , can I use some manual cutoffs such as ([50,100,300]) @jezrael ?

Comment: Yes, only change `[-np.inf, cutoffs[.1], cutoffs[.2], cutoffs[.3], np.inf]` to `[-np.inf, 50, 100, 300, np.inf]`

Comment: hi @jezrael , I 've a follow-up question on last week's thread. I also want to capture missing data in my bins such as [-np.inf, "", 100, 300, np.inf]  and label them as labels=['missing_data',1,2,3] . How can I do that?

Comment: I think it is not so - easy - first need filter data for missing and non missing, for non missing apply this solution and for missing assign 'missing data'. the best is create new question with sample data and expected output.